# How to Enable a button after one checkbox or more are checked?

Tags: android, button, if-statement, checkbox

I have a question say if I have a List of check-boxes but I don't know how many since they are generated by the user how can i Disable/Enable the delete button when at least one or more check-boxes are checked ?
I have this code so far 
I am new to programming so be specific please 
Thank you in advance.

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean DeleteButton) {
        if(cb.isChecked()){
            DeleteButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if(DeleteButton.isEnabled()){
            DeleteButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to know if one or more `CheckBoxes` are checked then create an `int` member variable and add to it when a box is checked

```
 public class MyActivity
{
    int count = 0;

    // oncreate...

   @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean DeleteButton) {
    count = (DeleteButton) ? count+1 : count - 1; // if is checked then add
                                                 // add 1 to count else decrement
    // I'm not sure about what is below but now you have the count
    if(cb.isChecked()){
        DeleteButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if(DeleteButton.isEnabled()){
        DeleteButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
};
```

Now the way to disable/enable the button if the count is greater than 0(you have at least one `CheckBox` checked would be like

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean DeleteButton) {
    count = (DeleteButton) ? count+1 : count - 1; // if is checked then add
                                                 // add 1 to count else decrement
        DeleteButton.setEnabled(count > 0);  // if count > 0 will be enabled
}
};
```

But I think you are confused on the second `param` of `onCheckChanged()`. It says whether or not the `Button` is checked, not what the `Button` is.

Comment: What i want to count is the check-boxes , by default the delete button should be disabled and when one of the cb or more are checked it should be enabled

Comment: i am now and i will get back to you as soon as possible , 
thanks man

Comment: would you be kind enough to explain to me the part with ""cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ch);
DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){"" and what you think is wrong with it

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to know. I don't see anything wrong with it

Comment: so I tired running the code and got two errors, 1-Cannot invoke isEnabled() on the primitive type boolean and the second "Multiple markers at this line
 - The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) 
  Object, int""

Comment: Yes, sorry, `DeleteButton` should not be there. That is whatever button you want to enable/disable

Comment: so instead of Deletebutton what should i put there , leave it empty ?

Comment: Give it a name. [Read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html#onCheckedChanged(android.widget.CompoundButton, boolean)) to know what it wants

Comment: @user2976492 you are very welcome. If that solved your issue, please accept by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so it may help others easier

Answer (score 0):

You can manage a list of checked items and whenever the checked state is changed, check whether the list is empty or has some items and then handle the enabling or disabling the button accordingly

```
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
        {
            if (isChecked)
                list.add(itemId);
            else
                list.remove(itemId);


            button.setEnabled(list.size() > 0); 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I misunderstood your question, but if you mean that you want to disable the delete button when one or more check boxes are selected, you could simply track the quantity of boxes checked.  The that value is greater than or equal to one, than disable the delete button.  For example:

```
int i = 0;

final Button DeleteButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
DeleteButton.setEnabled(false);
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
OnCheckedChangeListener ch = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean DeleteButton) {
        if(cb.isChecked()){i++;} else{i--;}
        if(i >= 1){DeleteButton.setEnabled(true);} else{DeleteButton.setEnabled(false);}
    }
};
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(ch);
DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
```

...

Comment: I think this should work, correct me if i am wrong the delete button is disabled , then  when the check-box (one or more )is checked else it shall be disabled ? but what about this part ""DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()""

Comment: Correct, the delete button will initially be disabled.  "i" will increase by 1 for each check box that is checked. If a check box is then unchecked, "i" will decrease by 1.  The last part, "DeleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()" was just copied from your original question, but should just be whatever you want when DeleteButton is clicked.